# How would I add to this code to make a keyword cipher?

Tags: python, encryption

So the goal of this program is to make keyword cipher, I have part of it started but I need help finishing the code.

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"
def encode_keyword(string, keyword):
''' Encodes the specified `string` using a Keyword cipher with keyword `keyword`.

```
    Parameters
    ----------
    string : str
        The string to encode.
    
    keyword : str
        The keyword to use in the substitution alphabet.
    
    Returns
    -------
    str
        The encoded string.
   '''
# student code goes here
uniquekeyword = ""
for letter in keyword:
    if letter.isalpha():
        if letter in uniquekeyword:
            pass
        else:
            uniquekeyword = uniquekeyword + letter
            
    for letter in alphabet:
        if letter in alphabet:
            pass
        else:
            uniquekeyword = uniquekeyword + letter
```

How would I go about finishing this, I have no idea, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Canned response: This homework question without any attempt gives no indication where the asker is actually stuck, and hence no indication what they actually need help with. As such, the question is unanswerable without doing the work for them and should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loops to iterate your inputs do other thing like append, strip etc.

for example first two of your program can be done as followes.

```
# input the text you want to encode
string=input("input string:")
# input the cipher string
key=input("input keyword: ").replace(' ', '') # remove all spaces
# alphabet
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
text = []

# remove duplicates from the key 
for i in key:
    if i not in text:
        text.append(i)# append only unique characters

    else:
        pass

# fill the rest with missing letters in alphabet
for i in alphabet:
    if i not in text: 
        text.append(i)

print(text)
```

And you can do the rest with similar way. Write your code in your own. Only ask for errors, problems you encounter while building the code.